# What is '&:id' Role.all.map(&:id) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is `&:id` in `Role.all.map(&:id)`. If `(&:id)` is shorthand for `{|a| a.id}`, then how to perform some method over any field individually. For example: `Role.all.map(&:id.to_s)`. It is giving error:

> wrong argument type String (expected Proc)

Comment: `Role.all.map(&:id).map(&:to_s)` Although this is both longer and less efficient than `.map{|role| role.id.to_s}`.

Answer (score 2):

So `&:something` is a shortcut to a process. It's the same as a code block being defined after a `do`, only it can only call a single method on each item in the array.

These three code examples will do effectively the same thing*...

```
Role.all.map do |role|
  role.id
end
```

In this one, the `do` and `end` are replaced with curly braces...

```
Role.all.map{|r| r.id}
```

And as we're only calling one method in that block, we can replace it with the shortened syntax you're asking about:

```
Role.all.map(&:id)
```

---

Aside to your question, there is an optimation by which you can get all the ids from Role.

The above block will recall all the rows from your `ROLES` table, initialize a `Role` object, then get it's `id` property. But ActiveRecord provides a method which will just retrieve the `id` property for every row in the table, and not bother creating a full-fat `Role` object for each one.

```
Role.pluck(:id)
```

This also works for a query on Role...

```
Role.where("name like '%user'").pluck(:id)
```

If all you want from the Roles is an id, this is a much more efficient way to get it.

---

<sup>* Sergio disagrees that they are identical because of some subtle differences in run order... You probably don't need to worry about this.</sup>

Comment: do/end and curly braced blocks are not _entirely_ interchangeable. There's a subtle difference in their precedence.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd have to say that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: It probably is, but as of now, this answer gives wrong ideas ("exactly the same"). Maybe add a footnote or amend the wording?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not even getting any rep for this :s

Comment: yes, you are :)

Comment: Btw, you know what I talked about, right? The difference in precedence?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I wasn't aware of it, but I have come across it, in similar discussions on the difference between `and` and `&&`. I find it a pretty tedious conversation and have yet to write any code in which it makes any difference.

Comment: Oh, it screws with me almost daily. Like there's a method call `foo do something end`. And I want to debug-print its return value. So I do `p foo do something end`. Bam, it stops working.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd just put the `p` inside the block... Each to their own, I guess.

Comment: "I'd just put the p inside the block" - not if actual block body consists of multiple lines with branches and such. Alright, I won't annoy you any longer, in this thread. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Have a good day, now :D